The Dirac equation negative solutions resolution
I've revisiting the problem of the negative solutions of the Dirac equation. I get the problem with the Dirac sea. The interpretation of the positron going back in time can work as a mnemonic math procedure, but it seems unphysical for me. Antiparticles must have positive energy; a electron and a positron annihilate to create a positive energy photon (experimentally verified), and due to conservation of energy, if the positron had negative energy, the photon wouldn't have energy at all.
So the Dirac equation should give a solution for the positron but with positive energy. The negative energy solutions seems to me like a good direction to new physics but from a incomplete equation due to what I reason above.
I might be totally wrong but in that case, please link me some real good textbook. I've read many quantum field theory textbooks that don't bother to reason about it and I'm losing hope. (Yes, I read all the related topics here also, but those go to CPT symmetry and none have give me a hint.)

Hm, any QFT book should talk about this. Do you understand the case of a real scalar field? The resolution is that the Dirac equation (or Klein-Gordon equation for a scalar field) is not analogous to the Schrodinger equation and its solutions are not best understood as one particle wavefunctions (except in certain limiting cases). You should understand the equation as describing a quantum field and associated with each mode is a creation or annihilation operator. See, eg, Tong Ch 2.

Try "QFT for the gifted amateur" from T. Lancaster

I think you can just read any good basic QFT textbook. They might not cover this problem in detail, but they would definitely cover the way to get the correct answer. The resolution to the "negative energy" issue is that the QM way to do things is just wrong. Once you recast the Klein-Gordon and the Dirac equations into field equations, the proper way to define the energy will find that these "negative energy" solutions have positive energies in the end.

I would recommend Advanced Quantum Mechanics by J. J. Sakurai.  The notation is a bit old fashioned, since it was written long before Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics (which Sakurai actually died before completing).  The book is, as the title indicates, an advanced one; it assumes the reader has a significant degree of facility with quantum mechanics.  However, it offers a very detailed and physically motivated discussion of what negative-energy solutions and charge conjugation mean in the Dirac theory, in sections 3.7 and 3.9; this kind of discussion is difficult to find in more recent books that concentrate more heavily on the field theory aspects of relativistic quantum theory.  The book explains very carefully how a positron corresponds to the absence of a negative-energy electron—including such counterintuitive facts as a negative-energy mode having momentum and velocity pointing in opposite directions, but a positron having its momentum and velocity aligned.

Indeed, I liked the discussion in this book. Thanks! I understand now how the hole in the sea acts like a positive energy particle and how the Dirac equation is limited when thought as a one particle equation.
